# Disable specific divs in CakePHP based on page selected

Tags: cakephp

I'm new with CakePHP and I need your assistance. I need to display a specific widget which is in the form of a div on a specific page i.e. my homepage and disable on the rest of the pages. Essentially I have been able to specifically display specific divs based on log in status as indicated below:

```
            <?php if (!$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')): ?>
                <div class="register link right <?php if ($active == 'register') echo 'active'; ?>"><?php echo $html->link('Register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register')); ?></div>
                <div class="login link right <?php if ($active == 'login') echo 'active'; ?>"><?php echo $html->link('Login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); ?></div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="logout link right"><?php echo $html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')); ?></div>
                <div class="myaccount link right <?php if ($active == 'myaccount') echo 'active'; ?>"><?php echo $html->link('My account', array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'summary')); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I was asking for any help with regards to displaying a specific div based on the selection of my homepage.

The pseudocode below indicates my the line of thinking I'm taking to solve this issue:

```
 <?php if (the selected page is homepage or default.ctp)?> 
     // set the display property for the desired div to none
 <?php else: ?>
     // do not set the display property for the desired div to none
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem of your code?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thanks for the reply. I'm essentially lost with why I'm unable to determine which view is selected within my if statement parentheses. I've edited my post and added pseudocode to indicate my line of thinking. In addition I believe once I determine the page I dynamically need to set the display style property of the div I intend on disabling as none. How is this do able dynamically in cakePHP? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In cakephp you cannot use directly `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')` in your view is bettere to do this into your controller:

```
$this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());
```

and into your view

```
if (!$authUser)
{
    //not logged
}
else{
    //logged
}
```

And if you wanna check which is the page you can try something like that

```
echo Router::url($this->last, true);
```

Is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can define something like:

```
$this->set('pageName', $pageName);
```

Then you can do in your view:

```
$class='';
if($pageName=='homepage') {
    $class=' hide';
}
echo $this->Html->div($class, 'your content here');
```

Also think about why you need a structure of this in your view. Maybe you can just not supply the content if it is not needed to the view? So you make the decision in your controller. That makes most of the time more clean views and the smallest amount of data needed in your view.

Comment: Hi Luc. I truly appreciate your reply. I'll try it out and post a message how it went